# My Galaxy Buds Pro won't connect in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, samsung

Recently I installed ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. after installing my Samsung galaxy bud pro which was working in windows now won't connect. when I try to connect using  **Setup button**, it keeps loading and nothing happens, other Bluetooth devices are working fine.
[image]

**I have tried many ways including**

**turn Bluetooth on using:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

**make it automatic on boot**

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

Comment: comment for the future visitors with the same problem. Answer of Juan was helpful only after I additionally restarted bluetooth through terminal as suggested by OP.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue with my Samsung Buds 2 Pro and Ubuntu 22.04. I solved it by following these steps:

1. Put the buds on their case but keep the case open.
2. While on their case, press both buds for a few seconds until the LED in the case starts to change between red and green (or blue and green, I don't remember).
3. Go to Ubuntu's Bluetooth settings and select your Buds.
4. Enjoy!

Comment: Just to update this answer. This was the way that it worked for me on Ubuntu 23.04 Just tested the buds 2 pro on it. Do note that the input quality is not bad, but is far from great. It is the same quality (input) that you get on the phone with them. Along with that, the output quality, at least currently, it is very dull and low. Yes, you can hear sound and speak, but overall, I would give the sound quality in general a 4 out of 10. 10 being a Logitech G935 for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the galaxy buds into pairing mode by steadily tapping both side of the buds for about 3 seconds or more until you hear the beeping sound. You know that it is in pairing mode if you hear a beeping sound every second. Go to Bluetooth settings in Ubuntu and you can see the Galaxy buds in the list of devices. Click the device name and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for answering but as you can see in the picture I shared , I did all you shared and on stage of connecting to it that where problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly using Ubuntu(I'm on Linux Mint), but in my case, I changed my device's Bluetooth visibility(from hidden to open).

Previously my Galaxy Buds got disconnected as soon as I tried to connect, but changing the Bluetooth visibility immediately solved the problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to my Samsung Galaxy Buds2 Pro using bluetoothctl command-line tool.
Open terminal and type `bluetoothctl` to open the tool.
Then in bluetoothctl type `devices` to list all bluetooth devices.
For me there were two devices with title "Galaxy Buds2 Pro".
Tried to connect both devices with `pair` command e.g.:

```
pair AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

For me the second try was successfull.

Note that having Ubuntu Bluetooth GUI open makes buds unusable and not connectable. Also Ubuntu Bluetooth GUI floods the bluetoothctl with lots of `[CHG] ...` log lines so better to close the GUI first.